# ruby gem to nuget packages mapping

Tags: rubygems, nuget

If nuget packages are supposed to be like ruby gems I would assume that there are some gems that have a nuget equivalent.

I am a looking for the asp.net mvc *nuget bundle* equivalent to the following ruby gems

- active admin
- elastic search / tire
- delayed job
- omniauth-identity
- spree
- vcr
- autotester

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because two package managers follow the same ideas it does not mean automatically that there are the same packages.

For some gems there may be libraries for .Net who try to solve the same problems. If you search for them you should use generic names to find anything: search for "search" and not just "elastic search" or "authentication" instead of "omniauth-identity".

The differences between Ruby and .Net are big. If you can't find what you are looking for inside NuGet you should try Google. If you find a project with a solution to one of your problems then you can try again in NuGet. But be aware that NuGet is not that much used in the .Net world as rubygems are in ruby. Most project can't be found in NuGet, even if more and more developers start using it.

Comment: thanks johnny, I guess i was just hoping that the nuget was more like gem in its use. I am a .net developer as a day job and I have been learning ruby at night. I really love all the gems. Thanks again.